# Перекодировка html-спецсимволов

Tags: html, c++

Программа должна парсить xml, приходящий от сервера. Есть проблема: русские буквы и спецсимволы приходят в виде html-кодов, например "&nbsp", "&lt", "&#1057" и т.д. Хотелось бы найти какую-нибудь С/С++ библиотеку, которая сможет перевести строчку из латиницы и html-кодов (без тегов) допустим в юникод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему бы вам для парсинга xml не взять какую-нибудь библиотеку, например libxml. Обычно такая функциональность в них встроена.

Comment: А, ну если так, то все отлично! Вопросов больше нет.